# Perform a task after all UI tasks are done

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

As written in the title, I'm trying to write a piece of code that executes after all UI tasks. I've tried to use the `Dispatcher` with no success, and ended up using a `BackgroundWorker` with `Thread.Sleep(1000)` which feels risky to me.

**Code snippet - using BackgroundWorker:**

```
BackgroundWorker bw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
bw2.DoWork += (o, e) => Thread.Sleep(1000);
bw2.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) => MyMethod();
bw2.RunWorkerAsync();
```

**Code snippet - using Dispatcher (which is not executed when I want it to):**

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() => MyMethod()));
```

I also tried to use `DispatcherPriority.Background`

Comment: Could you give more details? Why is it not executed when you want it to? When do you want it to execute? Instead of using a BackgroundWorker (blocking a thread), you could use a Task.Delay or a timer to introduce the delay.

Comment: then just try a higher `DispatcherPriority`. it will get executed.

Comment: @Andrew I don't know it's not executing when I want it to, which is after all of the current tasks in queue. I don't want to use a timer, as it feels risky to me. Is there any way to put a task at the end of the dispatcher queue?

Comment: Where are these tasks? It sounds like you should be awaiting the tasks' completion and executing this method when control is returned to you.

Comment: @MarkusHütter doesn't higher `DispatcherPriority` means it will get executed earlier?

Comment: @CharlesMager I'm using a third-party library that has tasks of its own, which update the UI. It seems that these tasks are being queued in the dispatcher.

Comment: What do you mean by 'task', then?  If they're synchronous, just execute your method after they return.  If they're asynchronous, then you need to use whatever mechanism they provide to notify completion as a way to determine when to execute your method.

Comment: @CharlesMager isn't there any way to set some code to be executed last, that is to put it at the end of the dispatcher queue?

Comment: It will always get added to the end of the queue (with priority taken into account)... but what if your tasks (that seem to be asynchronous) add their work to the queue after you do? You need to know when they're finished.  This is all guesswork, however - you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @CharlesMager I can't provide it, as we're talking about a third-party library which is copyrighted and I don't have it's source code. Can I still use `await` in that case? Maybe I should I just leave it as is and use `BackgrouondWorker`?

Comment: Well, we can't help unless you provide an example that demonstrates the problem. It doesn't have to be the real code, just something similar (read the link). It seems your current code only works by coincidence of the fact the time delay is longer than the time the 3rd party method takes to complete. That's not something I'd rely on.